# What is the closed-form of the KL-Divergence between two relaxed Bernoulli distributions?

Tags: kullback-leibler, variational-bayes, variational-inference

I've seen in multiple papers that use a relaxation of the Bernoulli distribution as defined in [Maddison et. al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00712.pdf) (here it is referred to as Binary Concrete) and they say that a closed form solution for the KL divergence between two relaxed Bernoulli distribution exists, but I can never find the explicitly stated solution. Hoping to have some guidance for how we can derive this closed form solution to the KL divergence.

The pdf of the relaxed Bernoulli is given by

> $$ \frac{\lambda \alpha x^{-\lambda -1} (1-x)^{- \lambda -1}}{(\alpha x^{-\lambda}+(1-x)^{-\lambda})^2} $$

where $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ are parameters of the relaxed distribution. If I take this route, I end up with an expectation that looks like there's no way to explicitly solve (i.e., I would have to use Monte Carlo sampling to approximate).

Any help in deriving the analytical solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: (1) It looks like you must restrict $x$ to the open interval $(0,1).$  (2) You appear to ask two different questions: do you want to compute the KL divergence or do you want the "expectation" you mention near the end?

Comment: I want to calculate the KL Divergence. The expectation remark at end end is if I used to definition of the KL divergence (E{log(p) - log(q)}) to try and derive the analytical solution, I get an expectation that looks like I would have to approximate, thus not closed-form.

Comment: I wouldn't think about this too hard, because working with the logarithm of the sum in the denominator will be intractable.

Comment: I was looking for the same kl divergence measure and i found out that Christos L. et al. answered to this question in the appendix of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01312.pdf. Check appendix B and C.